# Python skipping a step

Tags: python

Ok, I´m making a RPG for my first project in python and I have a problem, here is the code:

```
def getName():
    tempName = ""
    while 1:
        tempName = nameInput("What is you name?")

        if len(tempName) < 1:
            continue

            yes = yesOrNo( tempName + ", is that your name?")

            if yes:
                return tempName
            else:
                continue
```

and this is the main def:

```
    player.name = getName

while (not player.dead):
    line = raw_input(">>")
    input = line.split()
    input.append("EOI")

    if isValidCMD(input[0]):
        runCMD(input[0], input[1], player)
```

Now here is the problem, when i run main(player) it seems to just get the >> prompt when I start it and not the "what is your name?" string.

Whats the deal here ? Oh and this is python 2.7

EDIT: ok I added the () to the getName function, but it just keeps running dose´t proceed to check the name

Comment: Is your function definition indented?

Comment: You indentation for your question is off, this is essential in Python. Please edit your question, copy and paste your code as is, and then highlight it all pressing the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: What's nameInput? I would just use raw_input...

Comment: yes I did use raw_input, and the indentation was my fault in posting in the forum in the code its correctly indented

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the function.

`player.name = getName()`

In Python, functions are values.  In your code, you're setting the player name to a function, but not actually running it.  Adding the `()` will run the function and set `player.name` to the result of it.

Here is your fixed code:

```
def getName():
    tempName = ""
    while True:
        tempName = raw_input("What is you name? ")
        if not len(tempName):
            continue
        if yesOrNo("Is {0} your name?".format(tempName)):
            return tempName
        else:
            continue
```

And the main function:

```
player.name = getName()

while not player.dead:
    input = raw_input(">> ").split()
    input.append("EOI")

    if isValidCMD(input[0]):
        runCMD(input[0], input[1], player)
```

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect.  You **need** to indent correctly or it will not work.  You will be unable to write code that will work if you cannot indent properly.  I cannot stress this enough with Python.

Comment: Yep it was the indentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
if len(tempName) < 1:
    continue
    # oh no, you never ended the if statement
    # the rest of the code is still inside the if
    # so it never runs, because you already continued
    # to fix this, unindent the rest of the code in the method
    yes = yesOrNo( tempName + ", is that your name?")

    if yes:
        return tempName
    else:
        continue
```

The rest of the method is inside of your `if` statement, not just the `continue`. Remember, indentation matters!

You also never call the `getName` function, so naturally the code inside it will never be executed.

```
player.name = getName # this is not calling the function!
player.name = getName() # you need parentheses
```

Comment: thats it, thats the whole if statement

Comment: @Nathan Umm... What does that mean?

Comment: but I call the getName function in the main function

Comment: @Nathan No you don't, I don't see any `()` there

Comment: ok I fixed the parentheses, but it just keeps asking for the name now